# Flexiprovider elliptic curve public key from byte array

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm using the FlexiEC provider to generate an elliptic curve public key. Then I convert the key into a byte array. After that I want to get an instance of this public key from this byte array. Whenever I do this I get an exception.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import de.flexiprovider.common.ies.IESParameterSpec;
import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.FlexiECProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveParams;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry.BrainpoolP160r1;
import de.flexiprovider.pki.X509EncodedKeySpec;

[...]

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
CurveParams ecParams = new BrainpoolP160r1();
kpg.initialize(ecParams, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

byte[] pubKey = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
PublicKey pk = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" de.flexiprovider.api.exceptions.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Caught IOException("Unknown named curve: 1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.1")
at de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECKeyFactory.generatePublic(ECKeyFactory.java:205)
at de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(KeyFactory.java:39)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328)
at com.test.App.test(App.java:68)
at com.test.App.main(App.java:76)
```

How can I recover the key correctly from the byte array?

Answer (score 0):

I have some "ECIES", "FlexiEC" code which may be of reference for you. Here is the link:

[BadPaddingException: invalid ciphertext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713991/badpaddingexception-invalid-ciphertext)

If this helps, the credit goes to owlstead who answered the question for me which enabled me to complete the implementation.