# ECC key generation error

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

Hi i am trying to implement the code provided by anindonesian in [Flexiprovider - How to encrypt/de with formatted keypair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938781/flexiprovider-how-to-encrypt-de-with-formatted-keypair) on android.

I am getting a NullPointerException for  kpg.initialize(brainpoolP160R1);

I am new to Android and cryptography so any help would be appreciated.
Here i have just created a page that generates ECC key and encrypts/decrypts some data and displays it in a text box.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class ECC_page extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ecc_page);

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "BC");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ECGenParameterSpec brainpoolP160R1 = new ECGenParameterSpec("brainpoolP160R1");

        try {
            assert kpg != null;
            kpg.initialize(brainpoolP160R1); //I am getting the error here
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ignored) {


        }

        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

        byte[] PublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] PrivateKey = privateKey.getEncoded();

        Cipher c = null;
        try {
            c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESWithAES/DHAES/NoPadding", "BC");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] cipher = new byte[0];
        try {
            cipher = c.doFinal("This is the message".getBytes());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView eccencoded = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eccencoded);
        eccencoded.setText("[ENCODED]:\n" +
                Base64.encodeToString(cipher, Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n");


        try {
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey); 
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       byte[] plaintext = new byte[0];
        try {
            plaintext = c.doFinal(cipher);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView eccdecoded = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eccdecoded);
        eccdecoded.setText("[DECODED]:\n" +
                Base64.encodeToString(plaintext, Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n");


    }

}
```

I have inserted **apacheds-all-1.5.5.jar** in my  libs folder..

The error is 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator ECIES implementation not found
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
 at com.example.vinay.myapplication.ECC_page.onCreate(ECC_page.java:47)

Also please point out any errors in the code if possible...
The jar file to insert was suggested by android studio..

Answer (score 0):

The FlexiProvider is not Bouncy Castle (`"BC"`).

Try:

```
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES");
```

or:

```
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
```

for specific provider selection.

Note that Elliptic Curve key pair generation is identicial for ECDH (key agreement), ECDSA (digital signature generation) and ECIES (hybrid encryption). So you could also try:

```
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
```

or:

```
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "FlexiEC");
```

---

Adding the flexi providers instead of the Bouncy Castle provider may also help:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

is obviously also incorrect.

Comment: I am using bouncy castle itself and not FlexiProvider. In the link i mentioned there is an answer with Bouncy Castle implementation. Could you also tell me the answer in terms of bouncy castle itself? Also is the jar file I inserted the right one?

Comment: That was not all that clear from the context. No, that .jar is not correct, undoubtedly it is the Apache Directory Service .jar instead (at least if I remember correctly). You need the Bouncy Castle or Spongy Castle .jar's. Furthermore, you need to register the provider. The Bouncy Castle code does not have too much information, but I'm pretty sure that installation is explained.